# Pandas merging column 1 from dataframe A to dataframe B, when there are multiple matching rows in column 1 of dataframe B?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to get data associated with certain literary texts from one dataframe into another. In the first dataframe, there are two columns, one with title info, and one with the section of the novel. For example

| Title | Section |
| --- | --- |
| Book1 | beginning |
| Book1 | middle |
| Book1 | end |
| Book2 | beginning |
| Book2 | middle |
| Book2 | end |

In a second dataframe, I have categorical data about each book. For example:

| Title | American |
| --- | --- |
| Book1 | yes |
| Book2 | no |

I need to merge them on Title so that the 'American' values from the second dataframe duplicate in the first dataframe, as follows:

| Title | Section | American |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Book1 | beginning | yes |
| Book1 | middle | yes |
| Book1 | end | yes |
| Book2 | beginning | no |
| Book2 | middle | no |
| Book2 | end | no |

The closest I've gotten (based on the [pandas merge guide][Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) is:

```
df4.merge(df5["American"], left_on=["Title"], right_on=["Title"], how = "left")
```

Without have both left_on and right_on, I get an error demanding a right_on value, despite the documentation. However, now I am getting a KeyError: 'Title', even though Title is definitely a column header in both dataframes?

Comment: Is `Title` the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting key error just because you are trying to merge df4 with just "American" column of df5. Therefore it doesn't see the "Title" column on df5.

Try this one :

```
df4.merge(df5, how = "left",on="Title")
```

Comment: God, it's always something simple. Thank you for sending this, it is now working perfectly.